# Understanding .bmp file

Tags: image, bitmap, bitmapimage, bmp

I have a .bmp file

I sort of do understand and sort of do not understand. I understand that the first 14 bytes are my Bitmapfileheader. I furthermore do understand that my Bitmapinfoheader contains information about the bitmap as well and is about 40 bytes large (in version 3).

What I do not understand is, how the information is stored in there. 
I have this image:
[image]

Why is all the colorinformation stored in "FF"? I know that the "00" are "Junk Bytes". What I do not understand is why there is everything in "FF"?!

Furthermore, I do not understand what type of "encoding" that is? 42 4D equals do "BM". What is that? How can I translate what I see there to colors or letters or numbers?!

What I can read in this case:

**Bitmapfileheader**:

First 2 bytes. BM if it is a .bmp file: 42 4D = BM (However 42 4D transforms to BM)

Next 4 Bytes: Size of the bitmap. BA 01 00 00. Dont know what size that should be.

Next 4 Bytes: Something reserved.

Next 4 Bytes: Offset (did not quite understand that)

**Bitmapinfoheader**

Next 4 Bytes: Size of the bitmapinfoheader. 6C 00 00 00 here.

Next 4 Bytes: Width of the .bmp. 0A 00 00 00. I know that that must be 10px since I created that file.

Next 4 Bytes: Height of the .bmp. 0A 00 00 00. I know that that must be 10px since I created that file.

Next 2 Bytes: Something from another file format.

Next two Bytes: Color depth. 18 00 00 00. I thought that can only by 1,2,4,8, 16, 24, 32?

Comment: `BMP` files come in different subformats. But there's going to be parameters in the header for how many color levels, etc. Have you carefully studied all of the header arguments and what they mean and imply for how the rest of the data is represented?

Comment: @lurker I added some information

Comment: The byte ordering is little endian. So `BA 01 00 00` is hex `000001BA`, which is 442 (decimal). Any multi-byte values that represent a size or other single value (not pixels) need to be interpreted this way. The color depth in your second example is hex `00000018` which is 24 (decimal) bits. In your second example also, the size of the header is hex `0000006C`, or decimal 108.

Comment: @lurker awesome, thanks. I am very new to all this stuff and have no idea how to begin with. There are so many information everywhere. I will start with basic numbersystems now. How would I interpret the colors though?! There are just `FFs`?!

Comment: `FF` would probably be white. But 24-bit color depth means that each pixel is 3 bytes of data. Probably RGB. RGB white would be `FF FF FF` (red, green, and blue levels are all maximum of decimal 255). Black would be `00 00 00`. Bright, pure green would be `00 FF 00`, etc.

Comment: @lurker In what "encoding" is that written? Hex? If `00 00 00` is black, how can you distinguish between a Junk Byte and a black pixel?

Comment: The header should tell you the size of the data or how many pixels. Anything within the size of the data isn't junk.

Comment: @lurker Really? It says here (http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/article.php/c4909/Exploring-the-Internal-Structure-of-a-24Bit-Uncompressed-Bitmap-File.htm) that the rows need to be dividable by 4 - and if not - Junk Bytes will be added.

Comment: The link you give explains in detail how to distinguish junk bytes, so read through it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 bytes of information that you see "42 4D" are what we call the magic numbers. They are the signature of the file, 42 4d is the hex notation of 01000010 01001101 in binary.
Every file has one, .jpg, .gif. You get it.

Here is an image that illustrate a BMP complete header of 54 bytes(24-bit BMP).

[BMP Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrP9V.png)

The total size of the BMP is calculated by the size of the header + BMP.width x BMP.height * 3 (1 byte for Red, 1 byte for Green, 1 byte for Blue - in the case of 8bits of information per channel) + padding(if it exists).

Junk bytes that you refer, is the padding, they are needed if the size of each scanline(row) is not a multiple of 4.

White in hex notation if `ffffff`, being the first two red, green and blue.
While in decimal notation each channel will have the value of 255, because 2^8(8 bits) -1 = 255.

Hope this clears a bit(non intended pun) for you.